# Connection two laravel tables using third table

Tags: laravel, relation

I have two independent tables publishers and promotions. My third table promotion notify includes promotion id and publisher id. When I select one promotion I want to display the who are the publishers notified and  who are not notified. If you have any other method other than using third table please tell me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function in your publishers model like

```
 public function promotion()
    {
        return self::join('promotion_notify', 'publishers.id', '=', 'promotion_notify.publishers_id')
            ->join('promotions', 'promotion_notify.promotion_id', '=', 'promotions.id')
            ->where('users.id', $this->id)
             ->all();
    }
```

if it doesn;t help do check [this](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/).

It might be a better idea to use only 2 tables and define relation in model like:

In promotion model

```
public function publisher()
{
   return $this->hasMany('publisher');
}
```

In publisher model

```
 public function promotion()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('promotion');
    }
```

Comment: using pivot i can get the publishers who are notified. do you have any idea to get publishers who are not notified.

Comment: you have to use query, depending upon your model. If you have a Boolean (1 = notified and 0 = not notified) then your query will be similar to:

Publishers::where('is_notified' , '1')->get();

P.S is_notified is the name of column in your database that you are using to represent notified or not